# Assign variable to function - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

How do I assign a function to a variable then perform  action based on the result? Im using xcode 10.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  func foo(bar: Int = 10) -> Int {

   return 1

  }

  var demo = foo(bar: Int = 1) // cannot assign immutable expression...
  var test = 10

  let result = demo - test
}
```

Im expecting `result` to equal `9`

Error Im getting at `demo` is `Cannot use instance member foo within property initializer; property initializers run before self...`

Disclaimer: I'm new to swift; coming from ruby.

Comment: 1 - 10 is -9, not 9.

Comment: @i_am_jorf Correct but that's not the issue. See error.

Comment: The OP (and the code you have right now) has an error in the "demo" declaration. Remove the "Int = " portion in that line. That will always yield the error stated, which is not the same error as you have commented in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit mangled.

- Add underscores to the func signature to improve readability.
- Pass in a variable **only** when you want to overwrite the default.
- Recode this sample func to **not** always return 1, but return what was passed into it (or the default).

  ```
  func foo(_ bar: Int = 10) -> Int {
      return bar
  }

  var demo = foo()   // returns the default of 10
  var test = foo(1)  // returns the parameter passed in, which is 1

  let result = demo - test
  ```

EDIT: The actual question was lost in the errors fixed above. The OP is to have **foo(bar:)** be a computed property. So the final solution would be:

```
var _foo:Int = 10
var foo:Int {
    get {
        return _foo
    }
    set {
        _foo = newValue
    }
}
```

Tested in a viewDidLoad():

```
print(foo)  // prints 10
foo = 1
print(foo)  // prints 1
```

Please note:

- You **cannot** do anything like have a "constant default" to a computed property. Since this is an instance property, you set it once only.
- You cannot turn a function into a property. Yes, functions are first-class citizens in Swift, but this only means you can "treat them like a variable" by passing them into another function.
- I tried a few variations (adding "= 10" to the declaration, making the Int an Optional, removing the get from things, and it either doesn't build or crashes.

If you really need to have a default of 10, compute what is passed into things, **and** have it available globally, I recommend refactoring your concept to use one or the other of these solutions.

Comment: Yes but Im getting an error I dont understand: `Cannot use instance member foo within  property initializer; property initializers run before  self...`

Comment: You'll need to add more code. It sounds like you are coding something else than what you've posted. (1) Is foo inside a property? A specific class? An enum? (2) If in a class, what is the initializer? (3) In fact, what initializer **is** raising this error?

Comment: @Sylar Please update your question with additional context regarding this error.

Comment: Im inside  `UIViewController` sorry.

Comment: Ok. SO if you aren't in a playground, I believe if you (1) put my **foo()** as a "raw" function in that view controller and (2) put my calls in **viewDidLoad() - after the super.viewDidLoad() - ** and then looked at the result, things should build and run. That's what I meant by asking for more code. You must be putting your foo() someplace else.

Comment: Error is gone if I place the call in `viewDidLoad` but I need it as a global variable.

Comment: Search here and elsewhere for "Swift calculated property". That should show you how to code the remainder you need for this. **ALSO**, consider editing your title - it's misleading. Good luck!

Comment: I'll have a go at this later tonight (UK). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some syntax possibilities, depending on what you need the code to do:

```
var test = 10

// Simple value
let demo = foo(bar: 1)
let result = demo - test

// Closure calling function
let demo2 = { foo(bar: 1) }
let result2 = demo2() - test

// Pointer to function
let demo3 = foo
let result3 = demo3(1) - test
```